# Is  using an "Attached Property" a good practice for input capturing?

Tags: wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I am looking to find a generic way to support keyboard wedge scanning for my WPF TextBox controls.

(I am really a novice when it comes to more advanced WPF features, so I would like to ask if I am going in the right direction before I put a lot of time into research.)

What I am wanting to do is to add an Attached Property (or something) to my TextBoxes that will cause it to read all input into the box and then call a custom "ScanCompleted" command with the scanned input.

If an Attached Property is not a good fit for this, then is there a way to get this command on a TextBox without descending my own custom "ScanableTextBox"?

(Note: The criteria for a scan (instead of typed data) is that it will start with the Pause key (#19) and end with a Return key (#13).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this could probably be accomplished with attached properties (behaviors), but would be much simpler and more straightforward to simply subclass `TextBox` and override the `OnTextChanged`, `OnKeyDown`, `OnKeyUp` and similar methods to add custom functionality.

Why don't you want to create your own control in this way?

#### update: Attached Behaviour

If you really don't want a derived control, here is an attached behaviour that accomplishes this (explanation below):

```cs
  public class ScanReading
  {
    private static readonly IDictionary<TextBox, ScanInfo> TrackedTextBoxes = new Dictionary<TextBox, ScanInfo>();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScanCompletedCommandProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ScanCompletedCommand", typeof (ICommand), typeof (ScanReading), 
      new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand), OnScanCompletedCommandChanged));

    public static void SetScanCompletedCommand(TextBox textBox, ICommand value)
    {
      textBox.SetValue(ScanCompletedCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static ICommand GetScanCompletedCommand(TextBox textBox)
    {
      return (ICommand) textBox.GetValue(ScanCompletedCommandProperty);
    }

    private static void OnScanCompletedCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      var textBox = d as TextBox;
      if (textBox == null)
        return;

      var command = (ICommand) e.NewValue;

      if (command == null)
      {
        textBox.Unloaded -= OnTextBoxUnloaded;
        textBox.KeyUp -= OnTextBoxKeyUp;
        TrackedTextBoxes.Remove(textBox);
      }
      else
      {
        textBox.Unloaded += OnTextBoxUnloaded;
        TrackedTextBoxes.Add(textBox, new ScanInfo(command));

        textBox.KeyUp += OnTextBoxKeyUp;
      }
    }

    static void OnTextBoxKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      var textBox = (TextBox) sender;

      var scanInfo = TrackedTextBoxes[textBox];
      if (scanInfo.IsTracking)
      {
        if (e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
          scanInfo.ScanCompletedCommand.Execute(textBox.Text);
          scanInfo.IsTracking = false;
        }
      }
      else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text) && e.Key == Key.Pause)
      {
        TrackedTextBoxes[textBox].IsTracking = true;
      }
    }

    static void OnTextBoxUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      var textBox = (TextBox) sender;
      textBox.KeyUp -= OnTextBoxKeyUp;
      textBox.Unloaded -= OnTextBoxUnloaded;
      TrackedTextBoxes.Remove(textBox);
    }
  }

  public class ScanInfo
  {
    public ScanInfo(ICommand scanCompletedCommand)
    {
      ScanCompletedCommand = scanCompletedCommand;
    }

    public bool IsTracking { get; set; }
    public ICommand ScanCompletedCommand { get; private set; }
  }
```

Consume this by declaring a `TextBox` like so (where `local` is the namespace of your attached property, and `ScanCompleted` is an `ICommand` on your view-model):

```
<TextBox local:ScanReading.ScanCompletedCommand="{Binding ScanCompleted}" />
```

Now when this property is set, we add the `TextBox` to a static collection along with its associated `ICommand`.

Each time a key is pressed, we check whether it is the <kbd>Pause</kbd> key. If it is, *and if the `TextBox` is empty*, we set a flag to `true` to start looking for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Now each time a key is pressed, we check whether it is the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. If it is, we execute the command, passing in the `TextBox.Text` value, and reset the flag to `false` for that `TextBox`.

We've also added a handler for the `TextBox.Unloaded` event to clean up our event subscriptions and remove the `TextBox` from the static list.

Comment: Past experience has shown me that descending from existing controls causes difficulties/problems when implementing new features and during maintenance.

Comment: @Vaccano Very well; I have provided a solution that uses an attached property/behavior.

Comment: This worked FANTASTICALLY!  Thank you very very much for your help.  (I am sure I would have missed the Unloading part of things.)